# Which one is good RevenueCat or in_app_purchase library for Flutter In app purchases?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, in-app-billing, google-play-console

I have an application published in the Appstore and Google Play Store. Which one should I use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, while the *in_app_purchase* package is the official package from flutter, you have to write a complete backend that communicates with the Google Play server **and** the Apple Appstore server to verify your subscriptions and consumables/non-consumables what is really important to protect your app from fraud.

However RevenueCat's servers handle that validation process for you.

I personally always prefer using official packages, but if your app is generating lower revenue/has not so much users/... its probably worth it to use RevenueCat's Plugin in the beginning as you save a lot of time and it is free to use up to a monthly revenue of 10,000$

Later if your app is generating higher revenue you can consider writing your own backend.

Comment: If you didn't care much about security, couldn't you just have your app bypass the verification?

Comment: Yes, you could, but it is absolutely not recommended (and insecure). But it is possible